# Include jquery plugin in simple website

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I am fairly new to JS/jQuery and I am trying to include [RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask/blob/3.x/dist/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js) plugin in my project. I cloned the repo and created index.html file in the main folder so my directory looks like this:

```
\jquery.inputmask  
\\dist  
\\js  
...  
\\index.html
```

And my index.html file looks like this (simplified):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.inputmask.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.inputmask.bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#date').inputmask("99-9999999");  //static mask
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="date">
</body>
</html>
```

And this doesn't work so my question is: what am I doing wrong?
Do I need to clone jQuery library as well to get it to work?
Is my index.html file placed in the wrong directory?
Should I somehow set the path for the plugin?
Additional question: what if I wanted to use it in a Laravel project using composer? Simply placing path in composer.json and running composer update doesn't work either.

Comment: if you open up the dev tools in chrome, what are the errors?

Comment: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
../jquery.inputmask/jquery.inputmask.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
../jquery.inputmask/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
index.html:9 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

So I'm guessing the path is wrong since the files are in the \dist and \js folders

Comment: those errors mean it can't find the file, make sure the .js are in the same folder as your HTML

Comment: @user3209792 I would suggest just putting a direct path to another folder like jsScripts or something and it should work, just looks like a path issue

Answer (score 0):

you are double loading it, might be causing errors. took out the second script refrence and it is working for me. Also using the google CDN version of jquery.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.inputmask.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#date').inputmask("1");  //static mask
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="date">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can say for sure here is that you should not be calling both jquery.inputmask.js and jquery.inputmask.bundle.js  The latter has everything you need.

The bundle file has everything in it.  If you don't require the full feature set, you must choose a file that has the features you need.  As I was typing this another user responded that you are double loading, and that is the most likely reason you're running into problems.

The CDN call to jquery is optional.  You can certainly load it from your own server if you prefer as CDN's are primarily used for their bandwidth, but that doesn't necessarily mean that calling from a CDN is optimal.